# codeigniter error:syntax error, unexpected '1' (T_LNUMBER)

Tags: codeigniter

ajax driven search(date range is input).
search is working properly however when I am trying to convert status(value 1 & 2   is stored in database) as ON or OFF. I'm getting this error, when I change `if ('.$row->status.' === '1' )`   to   `if ('.$row->status.' === 1 )`  output is

`if (1 === 1 ) else if (2 === 1 ) else if (1 === 1 ) else`

```
 foreach ($query as $row)              
 {
$output .= ' 
<tr> 
if ('.$row->status.' === '1' )              //err
<td>ON</td>
else
<td>OFF</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: You can not “use if in strings” like that. Either use the ternary operator, or append something to the $output variable inside a proper if statement.

Comment: @pradeep hat still does not make `if` work “inside” a text literal.

Comment: No, to put it more precise, it is not performing a comparison here, because you are not in a context that recognizes this `if` statement _as code_ to begin with. You put it in a text literal/string context - so it gets treated as such, _text_ ...

Comment: i used ternary operator   <td>" .('.$row->status.'=="1") ? "ON" : "OFF". "</td>                    o/p is err: " .(2=="1") ? "ON" : "OFF". "

Answer (score 0):

You have to go through something like the following thought process...

"I want to output a string "On" or "Off" based on the result of $row->status.

So first you need to determine what the string , let's call it $on_off.
Then you need to create your string segment based upon $on_off.

```
foreach ($query as $row)              
{
  // Determine the ON/OFF string to output
  $on_off = ($row->status)?'ON':'OFF';

  // Create the String Segment.
  $output .= '<tr><td>';
  $output .= $on_off;
  $output .= '</td></tr>';

  // Whatever else is here...
}
```

The reason I have broken $output into 3 commands is to help break up the table tags into something a bit more readable and less prone to mistakes.

Comment: Does it make sense? If you could accept the answer that would be grand :)